# Change in scene clears viewpager

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a viewpager and two scenes which declares a different pager position. When I use transitionmanager to animate movement than viewpager becomes blank.

```
val transition = ChangeTransform()
transition.setReparent(true)
TransitionManager.go(scene, transition)
```

Also attempt to reset adapter fails - pager remain blank

```
pager.adapter = adapter
```

There https://developer.android.com/training/transitions#Limitations mention a limitation that attempt to animate items of adapter dependent classes will cause error, but this should not be a case

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter be sure to extend `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

example

```
class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
}
```

This did it for me